# Getting a 'Not Found' error on my website?

Tags: ftp, dns, hosting, dreamhost, filezilla

I'm trying to upload files to my domain that I'm hosting with Dreamhost. I connected to the server with FileZilla and I'm pretty sure I put the files in the right spot.

Their [tutorial](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Uploading_your_site) says to create a directory with your domain name like this: 'mydomain.com' and put your files in there. I put an index.html, p.css, register.php, login.php, and logout.php file in there. However, when I navigate to mydomain.com in Google Chrome, all I see is this:

[image] Does anybody know what could be causing this?
BTW I didn't actually create a directory called "mydomain.com" I used the domain I own.

UPDATE:

The directories are set up like this:

```
/
    mydomain.com
       public_html
           register.php
           main.css
           logout.php
           login.php
           index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. For some reason it wasn't working when the directory was labeled *mydomain.com*. I changed it to *mydomain_com* and it fixed it for whatever reason. Thank you to cevaris and Amazed for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure you have group read permissions on the file you are attempting to fetch?
 You want permission each file has a `755` permission, [here is how you would change a file permission in FileZilla](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-.html).

Also, make sure everything is in the `public_html` file.

```
public_html/index.html
public_html/p.css
public_html/register.php
public_html/login.php
public_html/logout.php
```

Comment: Did you put everything in the `public_html` folder? That is the default folder which web files are served up.

Comment: Okay I put all the files in a new directory called public_html (which is in the mydomain directory. Was that what I was supposed to do? It still says 'Not Found' though.

Comment: By default, files located in `public_html` folder are served up by the  web server. Keep in mind, this folder may be named something else. Could you updated your question with the full directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a file named `.htaccess` to your `public_html` directory. In this file, put the following line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Assuming the webserver is Apache (or a work-alike) this tells the server to send `index.html` whenever someone asks for `/`.

Comment: I added this file but it still says 'Not Found'