# public_html folder invisible

Tags: ftp

I have a website which I copied to [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/second/) location. The public_html folder was also uploaded with the other folders but it is not showing up. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried re-uploading it again, only by itself? Does the folder appear normally on your desktop?

Comment: It appears normally on the desktop but does not work.

Comment: Well the subdirectory /second is already public, you should actually upload the contents of the "public_html" directly to it and your website/html pages will show up. Your "/etc, /logs, /mail" folders should only reside in the root of your domain directory.

Comment: Beware I can see sensitive files containing user names and password hashes. (/etc/xxxxxx/shadow)

Answer (score 6):

As you are using DreamHost web hosting you wont have any control over ssh and chmod , chown commands. I think dreamhost wont use cPanel for shared hosting, they have their own control panel, so there is nothing you can do, Ask dreamHost support to reinitialize your public_html directory. Surely they will do that. I searched on dreamhost forum and found these link-

https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-13646-post-13647.html#pid13647

https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-128630.html

Currently in your case i saw that there is no issue related to public_html (technically "Document Root" ) directory  coz as your http://www.inspuratesystems.com/second/ is pointing to correct directory , and your documentRoot is parent of that directory, So if your documentRoot was wrong then there were no chance to access that that url, currently your domain is opening a correct index.html file which indicates that your documentRoot is there.

Create a index.html or home.html file there manually (from their web based file manager) and see if it is working or not, if it works then there is some issue with your uploading.

Answer (score 4):

Your hosting provider seems to be dreamhost.com

Please check out this thread, according to which public_html seems to be a special case on dreamhost:
https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-144453.html

and/or this:
[Getting a 'Not Found' error on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175169/getting-a-not-found-error-on-my-website)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the public_html folder has execute permissions

```
chmod a+x public_html
```

That will allow execute permissions for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's possible that server (apache?) hides folders named `public_html`? Also check that group `others` have read and execute permissions for that folder.

In folder /path/to/second/ run

```
chmod ugo+rx .
chmod -R ugo+rx public_html
```

to set folder visible.

Answer (score 0):

cpanel may handle the "public_html" folder in a unique way. Try uploading to a folder like: /home/yourusername/public_html/second/files/ instead of /home/yourusername/public_html/second/public_html/

If you are wanting to create a new distinct website at inspuratesystems.com/second/ you don't need a second "public_html" folder. Just put them in the /home/yourusername/public_html/second directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux or OS X server, you may need to change the permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if the folder is hidden attribute?

If you execute **ls -a** in terminal, you will know about it's existence. If it is present then please try giving it read & execute permission (using **chmod 555** command). Give write permission if you are planning to write something or take feedback from users (using **chmod 777**).

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of this options above but unfortunately none worked. Instead I discovered that in CPanel you have a "Preferences" tab and in that tab you have a "User Manager" function. You can there edit the ftp user that you created before in CPanel. On the "User Manager" funcion you can find the "Home Directory" configuration. On that home directory you just choose the "public_html". When you configure the user in the ftp account on your ftp platform, it goes directly to the path you defined in CPanel.